# How to reload a JSP page after all ajax calls get completed using javascript (without using jquery)

Tags: ajax, jsp

We fire n number of ajax calls from a jsp page, and we need to reload the page after all the ajax calls get completed. Can someone please advise as how I could do this using javascript(without using jquery).
Thanks.